# C++ alternative to OS.walk

Tags: c++, python, file-io

I want to write a C++ program that reads a number of files from a directory, the number of files is indeterminate. I know of a Python implementation - OS.walk, that does this job perfectly :

[Python OS.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

Does anyone have any ideas of a C++ implementation of this OS.walk functionality?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS are you working with? Are you opposed to using 3rd party libraries?

Comment: I'm working on Linux but I'd like it to be cross platform if possible! If the library is intuitive and works well then I have no opposition!

Comment: There's nothing in the standard library (yet) for doing this. Boost.Filesystem's [recursive_directory_iterator](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator) is a cross-platform alternative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 boost::filesystem::path path = boost::filesystem::current_path();
 boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator itr(path);
 while (itr != boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator())
 {
   std::cout << itr->path().string() << std::endl;
   ++itr;
 }
}
```

Taken directly from http://www.deanwarrenuk.com/2012/09/how-to-recursively-walk-folder-in-c.html

Which offers a good explanation of why you need the boost library to hide the differences in file systems.

Answer (score 4):

With standard C++ this currently is impossible.

But you can use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem) (look for `recursive_directory_iterator`) which probably will included in future versions of C++.